# Converting input from lowercase to uppercase using ASCII codes in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, string, ascii

This is my first question here, so I've done my best to make this a good question.

I am creating a program that essentially takes user input and converts all characters to uppercase. I am using a for-loop to scan for lowercase characters using corresponding ASCII codes.

I am able to do this just fine using a character array that is assigned a string in-code: `char text[] = "Text"`.

I want to be able to take user input and use it in the character array. I tried using `getline(cin,myString)` and assigning the character array with that, but it says array must be initialized with a brace enclosed initializer.

I kept the character array uninitialized because sizeof(text) isn't giving the correct size when the array is initialized.  I was reading about using pointers but I'm still a bit fresh on that topic. Below is the code I wrote:

```
int main() {
    // User input as a string
    char textConvert[] = "This text will be converted to uppercase.";
    cout << textConvert << endl;
    int endChar = sizeof(textConvert); //Only gives correct size when array is uninitialized
    for (int i = 0; i < endChar; i++) {
        if (textConvert[i] >= 97 && textConvert[i] <= 122) {
            textConvert[i] = textConvert[i] - 32;
        }
    }
    cout << textConvert;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The character constants have their corresponding character code value. For example, if you are using ASCII `'a' == 97`. No need to write the numeric constants yourself.

Comment: `sizeof(textConvert)` doesn't do what you think it does. Use `strlen(textConvert)`  instead.

Comment: `sizeof` an array gives the size of the entire array, not just the size of the part that is initialized. You may be thinking of `std::strlen` though it would be easier to just use a `std::string` instead.

Comment: You don't. I mean you don't hard-code ASCII characters, but use standard functions like [`std::toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper). You don't need your loop either, but can use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform). Finally, don't use [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

Comment: I appreciate that you tried to make the question a good one.
The comments and answer here are all correct - there is a better way of doing this (library functions are your friend) - but what I would say is, use paragraphs. A wall of text is hard to read. break it up to make life easier for people.

Comment: If you are trying to write production quality internationalized case conversion routines, it is ever so slightly a nightmare. 1) In Turkey, the uppercase form of 'i' is not 'I' but, 'İ' (and the lowercase form of 'I' is a dotless-i.  2)  In Germany the uppercase form of "Maße" is "MASSE" (five characters not four).  3) It gets worse, the lower case form of "MESSEN" is "messen", (so you need to know if SS goes to ss or ß).  4) It gets worse still, the lower case form of "MASSE" can be either  "Maße" or "Masse" depending on what the word means (it's capitalized because they are nouns).

Comment: If you are still learning about programming, this is all an irrelevancy though.

Comment: You can use `myString[i]`, you *shouldn't* copy from a `std::string` to a `char[]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Question:

> I tried using getline(cin,myString) and assigning the character array with that, but it says array must be initialized with a brace enclosed initializer

Here the compiler works out the size of the array needed.

```
    char textConvert[] = "This text will be converted to uppercase.";
```

If you want user input you need to allocate an array and specify size.

```
    char textConvert[50];
```

Now you can read a line and copy it into the array:

```
    std::string myString;
    std::getline(std::cin , myString);
    // Should check that the string is not more than 50 characters.
    std::copy(std::begin(myString), std::end(myString), textConvert);
```

But really there is no need to do this at all. Just use the `std::string` and loop over the string. Best to avoid C constructs like arrays and use the C++ constructs that stop you making errors.

### Size of String

This is not a good idea.

```
    int endChar = sizeof(textConvert);
```

This measures the size of the array (not the size of the string). There is also an issue that arrays will very easily decay into pointers. When this happens `sizeof()` will give you the size of the pointer (probably 4 or 8) not the size of the array.

To get the size of a string use `std::strlen()` (`include <cstring>`).

But really you should be using `std::string` the C++ version of string that does its own memory management and re-sizes as required.

### Magic Numbers

Prefer not to use magic numbers:

```
        if (textConvert[i] >= 97 && textConvert[i] <= 122) {
            textConvert[i] = textConvert[i] - 32;
        }
```

These magic numbers make the code hard to read. You can use character constants instead.

```
        if (textConvert[i] >= 'a' && textConvert[i] <= 'z') {
            textConvert[i] = textConvert[i] - ('a' - 'A');
        }
```

### Prefer the standard Library

But doing this manually is not recommended. You should use the standard library routines.

```
std::islower() .  // Check if a character is lower case.
std::toupper() .  // Convert a lowercase character to upper.

// include <cctype>
```

### C++ Example

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string   myString;
    while(std::getline(std::cin, myString)) {
        std::cout << "User Input: " << myString << "\n";
        for(auto& c: myString) {
            c = std::toupper(c);
        }
        std::cout << "Upper Case: " << myString << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: N.B that should be `toupper` not `toUpper`, and unless you're absolutely 100% certain that the input will never contain a `char` with a negative value (so pretty much any non-ASCII character) then you need to call `std::toupper((unsigned char)c)` to avoid undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dealing with ASCII, you can just use [std::toupper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper).

No need to write custom code to do it, the standard library has you covered.

Comment: Problems involving character conversions with Unicode usually revolve around the fact that typical Unicode character encodings are not fixed-width. The C library character classification and manipulation functions are for fixed-width character sets only. In particular, they won't handle UTF-8. They weren't designed for that.

Comment: @PeteBecker But they will not screw up either (they may not upper case all characters but they will not upper case any non ASCII character). This is because any code point that takes one than one `char` is not in the correct range to (ie all values are above 127)

Comment: @MartinYork -- I think you've left out an important qualification: C classification and manipulation functions **for ASCII-encoded characters** won't mess up UTF-8-encoded characters. Yes, most systems use ASCII, but people need to keep in the back of their mind that there are other character encodings, and they might run into one of them some day.

Comment: @PeteBecker: True. I support our Unicode masters and will fight on their side for world domination.

Comment: Custom code `return (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') ? c - 'a' + 'A' : c;` is around 50 times faster than `std::toupper`.